When I try to add metadata to my spl token on my Mainnet coin
For some reason when I try adding metadata to my spl token it never works, I’m using the program id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb and when I try to add metadata using my mint address it won’t work, is there something wrong that I am doing or maybe it’s because I’m using Pinata IPFS link for the URI? I have no isreal what I’m doing wrong
error: Found argument "'SoniXC"' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context USAGE: spl-token initialize-metadata [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] < TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS> ‹TOKEN_NAME> < TOKEN_
_SYMBOL> ‹TOKEN_URI>

Initialized a token 22 mint with the metadata extension like this.
Try removing the quotes if you're using them and see if there is a change.
spl-token initialize-metadata teseCZW7zZkyFJvHpDp7gB6rgvzYJa65XdPWL3Y7ivf Kobeni22 KB2 https://github.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/blob/main/metadata.json --update-authority  4kg8oh3jdNtn7j2wcS7TrUua31AgbLzDVkBZgTAe44aF

ref: spl-token documentation
TS/JS guide
